# Вот такая вот ошибкав node js: PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER

Tags: node.js, сервер, openserver

Использую локальный сервер 'OpenServer'.

```
node:events:368
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 2
at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:470:15)
at Parser.write (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
at Protocol.write (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket. (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
at Protocol.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Protocol._delegateError (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
at Protocol.handleParserError (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:380:10)
at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:478:10)
at Parser.write (D:\Programming\Web_development\My_sites\LF\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:33:29)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28) {
code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
fatal: true
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Возможно это решение вам подойдет [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140902/protocol-packets-out-of-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140902/protocol-packets-out-of-order)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как зайти в my.cnf?